# Find 3 max integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to find largest three elements in an array. So far I've come up with this but it doesn't work  properly (The output is 9 8 3):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max1, max2, max3;
        int[] test= {2,4,8,3,9,1};
        
        max1= test[0];
        max2= test[0];
        max3= test[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < test.length; i++) {
            if(max1 < test[i]) {
                max2= max1;
                max1= test[i];
            }
            else if (max2 < test[i]) {
                max3= max2;
                max2= test[i];
            }
            else if (max3 < test[i]) {
                max3= test[i];
            }

        }
        System.out.println(max1 + " " + max2 + " " + max3);
        
    }

}
```

I've managed to do the largest 2 integers but I can't do 3. How can I write the code using only 1 iteration through the array?

Comment: Your first condition should also set `max3= max2`, prior to setting `max2= max1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first 'if' statement you do not include:

```
max3 = max2
```

Comment: My first attempt was to do all it in one if loop, using the statement you suggested. But that also doesn't work properly.

Comment: @HazarUlaş Adding `max3 = max2` right below `if(max1 < test[i]) {` fixes the problem, so I don't know where you added that missing line, if it doesn't fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `stream`s for that job:

```
int[] test= {2,4,8,3,9,1};

String maxValues = Arrays.stream(test).boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .limit(3)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println(maxValues);
```

**Output**

```
9 8 4
```

Comment: I don't know what streams are, guess I have to do some research :)

Comment: Definitely, in many cases it will make your life a lot easier... ;)

Comment: What if I wanted to, let's say, find k largest integers? would streams still work?

Comment: If you mean the largest integers in the array, that is exactly what this stream is doing. If you change limit(3) to limit(4), it will print the 4 largest integers. If you need a list of the numbers instead of a String it is very simple.

Comment: @HazarUlaş Forget about that, you'll learn it later on. I bet you'd get an **F** if you tried handing in a solution to the assignment using streams, since it means you didn't exercise the writing of the code for find top 3 yourself. Besides, the stream solution is much slower.

Comment: This wasn't an assignment for me, I was just solving exercises on the internet.

Comment: @Andreas, who said it was an assignment? If it were an assignment my advise would be to try to solve it yourself instead of asking for help.

Comment: @Oboe but OP did that. He/she tried, got stuck and asked for help here.

Comment: @Oboe Shouldn't that be the advise regardless? Learn enough Java to solve the assignment/exercise/challenge yourself? Or do some research, aka search the web, which has many examples of how to do this. Or do the debugging yourself, instead of asking us to debug the code without even attempting it?

Comment: @f1sh Except that OP skipped the "debug the code" step before asking.

Comment: @Andreas Short answer is no. Long answer is if he is taking a class, he is under a learning program and every exercise has the purpose of incremental learning and the level of difficulty adapted for the student experience. On he other hand, if you are trying to write code by your self (and learning on the process), you need someone to help you fill your gaps and show some light of what other tools you can use (and learn).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Arrays.sort(test);
    max1 = test[test.length - 1];
    max2 = test[test.length - 2];
    max3 = test[test.length - 3];
    System.out.println(max1 + " " + max2 + " " + max3);
```